# How do I remove <meta name=... from head

Tags: layout, meta-tags, local, head

How can i remove 
`<meta name="keywords" content="keyword"/>` 
from head through layout.xml?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not possible via layout.xml, you have to copy the template file `page/html/head.phtml` to your theme and remove the following line:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getKeywords()) ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response!

I am tweaking a small SEO module and was looking for a unobtrusive way to remove the keywords tag.Would it be possible to do through an observer that gets access to the **head block**?

I tried to get something like this working but could'nt ->

`$headBlock->removeItem('meta_name','keywords')`

Comment: @Sebastianlockwood not without any black regular expression magic since there is no extra block or event for the meta keywords.